# multiple threads vs fork process in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to find a better way to run some cpu bound tasks using NodeJS. There are 2 options as I know, **fork processes** and [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html). So I have ran a benchmark between them and found out that fork process is faster.

So, I have some questions here:

1. Why is the fork process method faster?
2. Are the worker threads useless? Or what are the worker threads advantages, consumes less cpu/memory?

I'm running the code on MacOS(2.2 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3) using node v10.15.3

the benchmark code is in my [gist](https://gist.github.com/NeoyeElf/90c1b9568b03082fcb6caa9f547d7a1c):

threads pool library [microjob](https://github.com/wilk/microjob) and process pool library [node-worker-farm](https://github.com/rvagg/node-worker-farm) are used in my code as you can see. The running cmd is : `node --experimental-worker benchmark.js`

Comment: It's unlikely you need worker pools of threads or processes. If you have a server with a cpu bound task, you can just send a request to another server to do that cpu bound task.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think @gireeshpunathil's comment from https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1920 can help a lot:

> there is no single formulae that computes which method will be faster.
>   It depends on a number of parameters:
>
> - the running time of the job itself
> - the interaction of the job with the spawning code
> - the machine characteristics, specifically cpu,    memory and    scheduling
>
> the fork uses native fork and exec, that is heavy-weight than thread
>   creation. fork creates a new node instance with new v8, isolate, libuv
>   etc. worker does not create new node instance. forked process uses IPC
>   channel to talk to the forking process, if needed. workers use
>   in-memory buffers.
>
> So:
>
> - if the execution time of the microjob is too small compared to the    process creation, worker method will be faster.
> - if the job communicates with the driver, the frequency of    communication and the cost of communication will decide the winner
> - if the job runs as long independent piece of code with no    interaction, fork method will eventually prove faster (I think that
>     is happening here)